# file to saveas CSV format iin excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, csv, ms-word, powerpoint

i have used the following code for saving my active worksheet to CSV, but the output file is not found in that folder. What is the problem with the code?

code for your reference:

```
    Sub Save_CSV()

      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    SaveNAme = "INDENTED_BOM"
    SavePath = Dir("C:\Users\350153\Desktop\AUTOMATION (STRUCTURES)")

    Range("A1:D150").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select

    Selection.Copy

    Workbooks.Add
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:D").AutoFit

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SavePath & SaveNAme & ".csv" _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows, CreateBackup:=False

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    MsgBox "Task Finished", vbInformation, "Finished"

   End Sub
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please update your question with the contents of cells **B2** and **B3**.

Comment: B2 will be my filename and B3 is location where CSV file has to be saved.

Comment: Is it really easier to screenshot, publish the image on a site, and copy and integrate the link into the question, that to just copy and paste the code directly, so that we don't have to retype the full code?

Comment: B2 is my filename and B3 is file location in which it has to be saved as .CSV format @ Gary's Student

Comment: That isn't what was requested of you.

Comment: Does a file of the same name already exist in that path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without copy/paste, because the `Worksheet` object has a `SaveAs` method, so there is no need to do:

1. Create new workbook via `Workbooks.Add`
2. Copy range of cells from current workbook
3. Paste copied selection in to the new workbook from (1)
4. Save the new workbook from (1)

Instead, you should:

1. Invoke the `SaveAs` method on the worksheet
2. Remove the rows (1-4) which you don't copy in the previous code

It would look something like this, also modified to ensure file does not already exist. If file already exists, the `MsgBox` alerts you and then procedure will exit *without* saving.

```
Sub SaveAs_CSV()
Dim SaveNAme$, SavePath$, csvFullName$
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    SaveNAme = Range("B2")
    SavePath = Range("B3")
    If Right(SavePath,1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then SavePath = SavePath & Application.PathSeparator

    csvFullName = savePath & SaveNAme & ".csv"

    If Dir(csvFullName) <> "" Then
        'File already exists, alert the user and exit procedure
        MsgBox csvFullname & " already exists! The file will not be saved as CSV.", vbInformation
        GoTo EarlyExit
    End If

    ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=csvFullName _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows, CreateBackup:=False
    Rows("1:4").EntireRow.Delete
    Columns("A:D").AutoFit
    ActiveWindow.Close

EarlyExit:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```